# Count the number of letters, digits and special characters in C program

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, c-strings, isalpha

So here is my code and I am struggling with the `ispunct()`; it starts counting in 8 and in `isalpha()` it starts counting in 1 so I print it noAlpha-1, but in `ispunct()` it is awkward to put `noSpecial-8` to become accurate. I don't have any issues in digits. What might be the problem here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    
    char string[100];
    int i, noAlpha, noDigit, noSpecial;
        
       printf("Input the string : ");
       gets(string);    

 
        noAlpha=0;
        noDigit=0;
        noSpecial=0;
        
        for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
     
        if(isalpha(string[i]))
        noAlpha++;
    
        
        if(isdigit(string[i]))
        noDigit++;
        
        if(ispunct(string[i]))
        noSpecial++;
    }
        
        printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is %d\n", noAlpha-1);
        printf("Number of Digits in the string is %d\n", noDigit);
        printf("Number of Special characters in the string is %d\n", noSpecial);
}
```

Comment: First of all, ***never ever*** use `gets`. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it even have been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a **simple** example of input and expected vs. actual output. Also explain the `-1` in `noAlpha-1`. Also indent your code properly. It's hard to work with poorly indented code, even for top programmers.

Comment: Secondly, don't forget that strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. What happens if the user inputs a string with only five characters? What do you think happen when you loop over the null-terminator and continue into the other 94 characters in the array that weren't initialized?

Comment: I saw fgets() when I try to search this. Unfortunately in my school we used gets() on this. I will practice fgets(). Thanks

Comment: Don't forget return from main as well.

Comment: I am really sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow. So sorry

Comment: You are *probably* counting characters that you didn't actually input. Rather than `i<100`, use `i < strlen(string)`.

Comment: @Gnqz No explicit `return 0;` is needed since the C99 standard. If there's no explicit `return` statement before the closing `}` the compiler will implicitly add it. Note that this is a special case for the `main` function.

Comment: Don't use `gets` or `fgets` or `scanf` for this.  This is the right place to use `getchar`

Comment: @AdrianMole — or, better, use `string[i] != '\0'` to test when to exit the loop.

Answer (score 4):

The function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard.

Either use fgets like

```
fgets( string, sizeof( string ), stdin );
```

or scanf like

```
scanf( "%99[^\n]", string );
```

The entered string can be less than the size of the array string. So this loop

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you should use

```
for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

It is better to rewrite the if statements like if-else statements

```
    unsigned char c = string[i];

    if( isalpha( c ) )
    {
        noAlpha++;
    }
    else if( isdigit( c ) )
    {
        noDigit++;
    }
    else if( ispunct( c ) )
    {
        noSpecial++;
    }
```

So the output will look like

```
    printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is %d\n", noAlpha);
    printf("Number of Digits in the string is %d\n", noDigit);
    printf("Number of Special characters in the string is %d\n", noSpecial);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    
    char string[100];
    int i, noAlpha, noDigit, noSpecial;
        
       printf("Input the string : ");
       scanf( "%99[^\n]", string );    

 
        noAlpha=0;
        noDigit=0;
        noSpecial=0;
        
        for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
     
        unsigned char c = string[i];

        if( isalpha( c ) )
        {
        noAlpha++;
        }
        else if( isdigit( c ) )
        {
        noDigit++;
        }
        else if( ispunct( c ) )
        {
        noSpecial++;
        }
        }
        
        printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is %d\n", noAlpha-1);
        printf("Number of Digits in the string is %d\n", noDigit);
        printf("Number of Special characters in the string is %d\n",noSpecial);
}
```